# TTL for Integration Runtime is not working

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline composed from subpipelines that run sequentially. Some of these subpipelines run data flows with the same IR (30 min TTL), but all the data flows are using 5 minutes for startup time.

I remember this was working before. Like a month ago. I guess it may be a bug in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Microsoft added a check box in the Integration Runtime creation process...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Custom Integration Runtime  - doesn't apply to Auto Resolve Integration Runtime